# Xamarin, How to add more columns in list view in xaml or should i use a grid for column 1 ,2 ,3 4, 5 for row 1 but i don't know how to access it

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

So in my database i'd like to have in every row these columns : rainvolume1 from an entry, rainvolume2 from an entry, rainvolume3 (entry),  date, time.  This doesn't work below. I don't know how to show the rest of the columns.

```
//I added another text cell but it's not showing. 

<ListView x:Name="postListView" >
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<!-- from the post.cs -->
<TextCell Text="{Binding rainvolume1}"/> 
<TextCell Text="{Binding rainvolume2}"/>
</DataTemplate>            
</ListView.ItemTemplate>

//this will only show one column
<ListView x:Name="postListView" >
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<!-- from the post.cs -->
<TextCell Text="{Binding rainvolume1}"/>     
</DataTemplate>            
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

I'd like to show: rainvolume1 in column1, rainvolume2 in column 2, rainvolume3 in column3, date column4, time column5 if can combine date and time in 1 columns that would be great too.

Comment: you can only have once Cell in a ListView template.  You should use a ViewCell containing a Grid that has a column for each element you want to display.  Then you can assign a Label to each column of the Grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, you want to display data from you database in ListView, there are 5 columns, so you can do template in ListView.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding models}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding rainvolume1}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding rainvolume2}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding rainvolume3}" />
                            <Label IsVisible="False" Text="{Binding date1}" />
                            <Label
                                x:Name="labeltime"
                                IsVisible="False"
                                Text="{Binding time}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding date1, Converter={StaticResource converter1}, ConverterParameter={x:Reference labeltime}}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

If you want to combine date and time in one column, you can use Converter in ListView.

```
class dateconverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string date =value.ToString();
        var labeltime = parameter as Label;
        string time = labeltime.Text;



        string dt1 = date + " " + time;
        return dt1;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your XAML code is confusing, you're creating two ListViews with the same name. That doesn't work because the compiler will not know which one you want to reference if you call the views's name by code.

The ListView's `DataTemplate` component lets you create a template that will display the information of every object within a list. The `ListView` **is not a table**, it doesn't have columns. It is a list of rows, containing one row per element in a list, and you can display the element's information however you want. This is a ListView example:

[image: ListView example]

Check [this tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/WorkingWithTables/) to see how to populate ListViews and format how the data is displayed.
If you need to display elements like a table, with columns and rows, I'd recomend another view like the [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.Grid?view=xamarin-forms), which give you options to set column widths and row heights.